# NSPredicate equals nil in NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I want to fetch object from Core Data using `NSPredicate`. I made it, but when I launch `NSFetchRequest`  the `NSPredicate` equals nil shown in the console. I have the Xcode 6.4, Swift 1.2. I restarted Xcode but I get the same result. How can I make it?

```
func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Car")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "personCar", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "personRelationship.namePerson contains[c] %@", currentPerson)
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    println(fetchRequest)
    return fetchRequest
}
```

The message from the console

```
<NSFetchRequest: 0x1700db040> (entity: Car; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(personCar, ascending, compare:)"
)); batch size: 50; type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `fetchRequest.predicate` value is set (i.e., is not **nil**).

The code in your post *does* show that the `predicate` value is assigned. However,  when the `NSFetchRequest.predicate` attribute is not set then the println console message will display `((null))` for the `predicate` value.